# Admob is not working on android studio 2.0

Tags: android, admob, ads, banner

Admob banner in main activity is not showing the ads and the banner. I tried on multiple smartphones the problem persist. But ads banner shows on main.xml design preview.

Here's my code:

**Main.java**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;



public class `MainActivity` extends Activity
Button sharebutton;
public MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

**String**

```
string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-5281300412510582/8914765755</string>
```

**build.gradle**

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/x">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/onww"
        android:id="@+id/warnone"
        android:background="#69f830"
        android:layout_above="@+id/warntwo"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/warntwo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/warntwo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="35dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/twow"
        android:id="@+id/warntwo"
        android:background="#fec357"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/threew"
        android:id="@+id/warnthree"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/warntwo"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/stop"
        android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_below="@+id/warnthree"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/whrmymoney"
        android:background="@drawable/moneycash"
        android:layout_above="@+id/warnone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/share"
        android:id="@+id/share1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/warnone"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/adView" />
       </RelativeLayout>
```

**manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xxx.xxxxx">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".x"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_x_xxvby"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>


<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please change your ids and and adsize@Robzorc.I have given a solution,please check it.

Comment: Not problem in android studio 2.0 please try to change your admob banner id with default or new then try.i fetch same problem but try new id to solve this.

Comment: issues persist, tried new ad id , tested with diff app and i only tested on mobile data , WiFi haven't test yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xml contains two Adviews with same id.Please change your ids.
Also change your adsize to SMART_BANNER:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: tried as you advice, same issues persist. Need advice! is my main.java correct? i follow the steps from Admob website. @CrazyAndroid

Comment: 05-14 14:09:52.834 4159-4255/com.apps.wheres W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
05-14 14:09:52.841 4159-4159/com.apps.wheres W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

Comment: Make a new Ad unit ID in a separate project and check if it is loading your ad or not.Your java is code is right,there is no problem there@Robzorc.

Comment: tried as u say , W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2  , 05-14 21:16:27.053 31146-31146/com.kit I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("0DFE6721603E1DB4FBF0AE442F098C48") to get test ads on this device.
05-14 21:16:27.484 31146-31158/com.kit W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
05-14 21:16:27.484 31146-31146/com.kit I/Ads: Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
05-14 21:16:27.484 31146-31146/com.kit W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 2

Comment: Check whether your ad is loading in the emulator or not.

Comment: On emulator API22 is Working , it's display the test ad from admob awesome.  but when debug using smartphone API15, 16 and 18 nothing show up. Advice: do I need signed apk for smartphone in order get ads display.@CrazyAndroid

Comment: Change your  minSdkVersion to 15 to  test your device for Ad@Robzorc.No you do not need any signed apk for the display.

Comment: To test your add in an API always check your targetsdk and minimum sdk.If you are trying to run your app in API 22 but your target sdk is 16,you will never be able to load your app properly.@Robzorc

Comment: Thanks for the advice, my minSdkVer is 15 when first created , do I need to manually add in any other file?

Comment: No brother,Just do change it in your gradle file and you are done.Enjoy happy coding.@Robzorc

Comment: your answer help me a lot , but i am still unable to get my ads display on smartphone , in emulator works fine, Guess i need to test on faster internet connection for smartphones.@CrazyAndroid

Comment: No bro its not compulsory that you need a faster internet.I think its the problem of SDK. just once again go through your minimum sdk and compile sdk.

Comment: check out my build.gradle , is it correct? @CrazyAndroid

Comment: Bro I don't know where else to edit min sdk and compile sdk!

Comment: Give me the list of smartphones you are checking@Robzorc

Comment: HTC butterfly API18 , Sony Xperia sola API15  , Lenovo 850+ API17 , Asus Zen fone 5 API 20.@CrazyAndroid

Comment: Please check once by connecting it to WIFI,whether the ad is loading or not.@Robozorc